# Java test soap web service junit

Tags: java

I would like to write java unit tests with eclipse on a soap client web service, I'm not sure which library used to mock requests. All the class of the wsdl were generated with eclipse

Comment: do you mean some mock server which can provide you mocked response?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it